# Getting values from datatable

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatable

I want to get a number value from datatable. However below code returns nothing when it is actually has a value.

```
Object num = TopActivityDT.Rows[0][1];
Label2.Text = num.ToString();
```

I also tried these but didn't work;

```
var num = TopActivityDT.Rows[0][1];
Label2.Text = num.ToString();

string num = TopActivityDT.Rows[0][1].ToString();
Label2.Text = num.ToString();
```

Comment: Did you checked if your datatable has any record and second column of the datatable has correct value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please make sure that your datatable has rows in it either in debug mode or by following assingment.

```
Label2.Text = TopActivityDT.Rows.Count.ToString();
```

If it returns more than 0 then make sure your columns have proper value in it and try to make assignment like following

```
Label2.Text = Convert.ToString(x.Rows[0][1]);
```

Infact i would suggest to check for DBNull and then do assignment like following

```
Label2.Text = x.Rows[0][1] == DBNull.Value ? "" : Convert.ToString(x.Rows[0][1]);
```

Comment: yes, it returns null. however, I know that it is not null because i see that valeus in my chart.

Comment: You need to make sure you are pointing to correct column number then. As i mentioned first check if it has rows, then make sure which column has value you need and mention that correctly. it should work then.

Comment: It returns 13 and here is the image that datatable columns are not null = http://i.hizliresim.com/PnNY48.png